# Anyone using KVM with Spice protocol?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have a few KVM machines running in a Ubuntu 10.04 64bits host (all Windows xp Guest).

I want to give a better desktop experience for the users (now they're using remote desktop to them) and run the KVM with spice enabled (so they can use spice client).

I have it running in lab, and the experience is much better.

Do you guys have it running on your own, somewhere, in production.. etc with good results?

As I read, RedHat and IBM are investing a lot in the Spice protocol, and looks promising (at least, right now, works very well).

Anyone?

Thanks a lot ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Spice enabled KVM packages should land in the development release this week (hopefully).  I'm currently reviewing them before sponsoring them.

I'm not sure if anyone is currently backporting them to a stable release.